# Getting a substring from StringBuilder with end index calculated through lastIndexOf throwing ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, android, indexoutofboundsexception, stringbuilder

```
sb.substring(0, sb.lastIndexOf("\n"));
```

The above code has crashed (non reproducible) in the code. The exact Crashlytics reported error is below (giving the exact error if maybe length or any other aspect is causing an error here):

> Fatal Exception: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException length=4606;
>   index=4620

Can somebody please help me in understanding what can be the root cause here?

Comment: Perhaps the `StringBuilder` has become corrupted due to multi-threaded access?

Answer (score 0):

if you are in a single threaded environment or don’t care about thread safety, you should use StringBuilder else use StringBuffer.

Comment: Still crashing even after switching to StringBuffer.